# Can textbox input in C# be restriced to a formatted type?

Tags: c#, .net

I'd just like to know if there's a function/way to restrict input to a textbot to a formatted type e.g. a user can only enter a **date** type into a textbox; or a function similar to to the C scanset that I can use to achieve the same functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are writing a desktop app you could use the [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx).

> The MaskedTextBox class is an enhanced
>   TextBox control that supports a
>   declarative syntax for accepting or
>   rejecting user input. Using the Mask
>   property, you can specify the
>   following input without writing any
>   custom validation logic in your
>   application:
>
> - Required input characters.
> - Optional input characters.
> - The type of input expected at a given position in the mask; for
>     example, a digit, or an alphabetic or
>     alphanumeric character.
> - Mask literals, or characters that should appear directly in the
>     MaskedTextBox; for example, the
>     hyphens (-) in a phone number, or the
>     currency symbol in a price.
> - Special processing for input characters; for example, to convert
>     alphabetic characters to uppercase.

Comment: You could have also derived from TextBox and created your own custom textbox. I have done this on a few occassions to achieve a numeric textbox!

Comment: This is a WinForms control, so in WPF you would need to make your own custom one, as James said.

Answer (score 2):

The tool that would work best in this scenario is the Masked Edit Textbox.

Answer (score -3):

There is no such functionality, unless you use NumericTextBox and DateTimePicker controls.

But as always, you can define your own controls and logic by overriding the default TextBox control.